# How to show only categories with products with CakePHP's tree behavioral?

Tags: php, cakephp, mptt

I'm using CakePHP's tree behavior and need to know if there is any products in category or it's subcategories since I don't want to view empty categories.

I would like to do something like this:

```
$cat = $this->Category->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));
    $test = $this->Category->find('threaded', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.lft >=' => $cat['Category']['lft'], 
            'Category.rght <=' => $cat['Category']['rght'],
            'Product.InStock >'=>0 //NOT WORKING
        )
    ));
```

That would be a starting point to unset not needed array dimensions. In database, categories hasMany products.

What could be best solution to this problem? Is it possible to avoid Product->find in foreach loop with category_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested

```
$this->Category->Behaviors->attach->('Containable');

$cat = $this->Category->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));

    $test = $this->Category->find('threaded', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.lft >=' => $cat['Category']['lft'], 
            'Category.rght <=' => $cat['Category']['rght']),
         // use containable behaviour and apply the condition
        'contain'=>array('Product'=>array('conditions'=>
                                          array('Product.InStock >'=> 0)
                                     )
                         )
        ));
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you! Now I just need to get rid of all the "dead end" without products categories. Maybe multiple foreach-structures or what?

Comment: I forgot to mention in my answer, but that sort of query and performance can get out of control quite easily, if you have thousands of products. You'll want to monitor that and see how it goes. Probably worth using the `fields` array within the `contain` array and selecting only the fields you need from `Product` and limiting it/using pagination.

Comment: Thanks, I keep eye on it. Load time is now about 0.25 sec and it's not very high traffic site so it doesn't matter yet.